# TeamCity separate test data from tests

Tags: java, teamcity

I have a Java application with function tests that uses a huge amount of data. The tests are run from TeamCity. There are several agents running the tests. I'd like to separate the data into another project that will basically only do an update from version control and store the data on a local machine running the agent.

Then I need every agent to know where on the local machine are the data located and pass it as a parameter to the main build.

Is there a way to configure the builds this way?

---

The motivation is that the cleaning of a work directory removes this data when they are not separated. Cleaning is sometimes necessary, but never because of the test data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do a separate build, and other build would depends on this one, and probably using artifacts you can get the files you need. Or you in the build, you use a custom location where the agent would clone the repository, so you can know where it is, and use it as a parameter for your others builds.

Comment: Ended up with a separate build that puts the test data on a fixed path, but inside the agent's work directory. It works ok, but the data gets deleted from time to time.